# Why does this twisted server interact wrongly with a process?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, ipc, twisted

The server is at https://github.com/EmeraldHaze/Socketd/blob/master/Serv.py ; the process is at https://github.com/EmeraldHaze/QFTSOM/blob/master/main.py 
A client too test this is at http://www.kongregate.com/games/EmeraldHaze/this-is-why-we-have-maps ; port forwarding and whatnot is set up correctly.
The point is that someone connecting too the server sends something like {"IP":"123.456.789.012"}, then a process is made for him, then the IO streams of the process and the user are connected. The reality is that the process outputs something, the user sees it, the user gives some input, the server gets it (and logs it), then nothing happens. Any ideas why? The buffers should be flushed.

Comment: Could you provide a complete, *minimal* example that shows your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, I solved this. It was becouse sys.stdin.readline() stops blocking when it gets a \n, but either twisted or the client strip them off, meaning it will block indefinitly despite getting input.